# Collecting distinct values with key does not work as expected

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I have the following XML:

```
<planning>
  <visit>
    <nr>001</nr>
    <action>
      <code>CA01</code>
    </action>
    <action>
      <code>CA02</code>
    </action>
    <action>
      <code>CA03</code>
    </action>
    <action>
      <code>CA01</code>
    </action>
    <action>
      <code>CA02</code>
    </action>
    <action>
      <code>CA03</code>
    </action>
  </visit>
  <visit>
    <nr>002</nr>
    <action>
      <code>CA01</code>
    </action>
    <action>
      <code>CA02</code>
    </action>
    <action>
      <code>CA03</code>
    </action>
    <action>
      <code>CA02</code>
    </action>
    <action>
      <code>CE03</code>
    </action>
    <action>
      <code>CE03</code>
    </action>
  </visit>
</planning>
```

I wish to list distinct codes for each visit.
My XSLT for this is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml"
              indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:key name="codekey" match="action" use="code"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <visits>
      <xsl:for-each select="/planning/visit">
        <visit>
          <nr><xsl:value-of select="nr"/></nr>
          <codes>
            <xsl:for-each select="action[generate-id()=generate-id(key('codekey',code)[1])]">
              <xsl:value-of select="code"/>
              <xsl:if test="not(position()=last())">
                <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
              </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </codes>
        </visit>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </visits>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That, however, outputs

```
<visits>
    <visit>
        <nr>001</nr>
        <codes>CA01, CA02, CA03</codes>
    </visit>
    <visit>
        <nr>002</nr>
        <codes>CE03</codes>
    </visit>
</visits>
```

I expected the codes of visit 002 to be `CA01, CA02, CA03, CE03`.
Indeed, when I transform only visit 002:

```
<planning>
  <visit>
    <nr>002</nr>
    <action>
      <code>CA01</code>
    </action>
    <action>
      <code>CA02</code>
    </action>
    <action>
      <code>CA03</code>
    </action>
    <action>
      <code>CA02</code>
    </action>
    <action>
      <code>CE03</code>
    </action>
    <action>
      <code>CE03</code>
    </action>
  </visit>
</planning>
```

the output is as I expected:

```
<visits>
    <visit>
        <nr>002</nr>
        <codes>CA01, CA02, CA03, CE03</codes>
    </visit>
</visits>
```

What should I do to get te result I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either `use="concat(../nr, '+', code)"` or `use="concat(generate-id(..), '+', code)"` for the key definition and of course then use the same expression where you use the key function e.g. `action[generate-id()=generate-id(key('codekey', concat(../nr, '+', code))[1])]`.

Comment: I think the second form should be use="concat(generate-id(..), '+', code)". Then it works.

Comment: @Arjan, yes, you are right, I corrected the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I understand now why my method didn't work: the key's match="action" matches action nodes from the whole document, not just from within the visit node the XSLT happens to be in, as I believed. So in the second visit node the test of the for-each select fails for CA01 because the CA01 is not the key's first CA01. It succeeds for CE03 because it is the key's first CE03.